# Redux Reducer function has empty state

Tags: react-redux, redux-thunk

This is a bit weird for me, because my state array is empty in function of the same reducer while not in other.

So, my reducer looks like this -

```
export function booksHasErrored(state = false, action) {
     //console.log(action.type);
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'BOOKS_HAS_ERRORED':
            return action.hasErrored;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function booksIsLoading(state = false, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'BOOKS_IS_LOADING':
            return action.isLoading;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function books(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'BOOKS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return action.books;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function updateBook(state = [], action) {
    console.log('updateBook');
    console.log(state);
    console.log(action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'BOOK_UPDATE':
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In this reducer, function books has got state with a list of all my books. But, the updateBook function always shows empty state array. In my web application, first books function is called to get a list of all my books from API call and then update function is called and user navigates to update the book. I expected my updateBook function to receive the state object with all its items.

This is how I am combining my reducers -

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {routerReducer} from 'react-router-redux';
import { books, booksHasErrored, booksIsLoading,updateBook } from './books';
import { search, searchHasErrored, searchIsLoading } from './search';
import { authors, authorsHasErrored, authorsIsLoading } from './authors';

//import authors from './authors';
//console.log(books);
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ books,booksHasErrored,booksIsLoading,updateBook,authors,search, searchHasErrored, searchIsLoading, authors, authorsHasErrored, authorsIsLoading,routing:routerReducer});

export default rootReducer;
```

Please let me know if you need more information and I will add it here.

Comment: Do you have to declare the parameter state as empty in the function?
Maybe this is impacting, try to set state instead of state = []

Comment: state = []  is just an es6 way of setting a default empty array.

Answer (score 1):

I might have discovered your problem, you are not returning the full state, you are returning the action

```
export function books(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'BOOKS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return action.books;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

You need to create a new state and mutate it, and then return it, example:

```
export function books(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'BOOKS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
            return state.set('books', action.books);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Can you change it and see if it works?